# character that replace all if statement

Tags: apex

I have a simple question but I didn't manage to find an answer online.

My goal is to make a if statement that consider a URL.

The if loop would check the url input by me in the visual page and then depending on which url it is , it would use a different function.

To be clearer : if the link is : www.YYY.com/cde**** then apply the function yyy()

if the link is www.YYY.com/abc***

The character *** is missing from my apex coding knowledge but I hope that it is not from yours,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing it like that with the * character, I used string.contains with the beginning of the link

Worked perfectly